# Using ion-slide-box in a scrollable ion-content view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slideshow, ionic-framework

I have an ionic view with the following markup:

```
<ion-content scroll="true">
    <ion-list>
        ... some ion items...
        <ion-item> 
            <ion-slide-box>
                <ion-slide ng-repeat="image in images">
                    <div class="background"></div>
                        <img src="{{ image.src }}">
                    </div>
                </ion-slide>
            </ion-slide-box>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
<ion-content scroll="true">
```

Everything works fine except that when I use the `ion-slide-box` and slide the images in it horizontally then the vertical scrolling of the surrounding view is too sensitive and scrolls in between.

Did anyone have the same problem or knows if there is an easy way to disable scrolling as long as the slide box is sliding?

Comment: what ionic version you are using ?

Comment: ionic version 1.3.16

Comment: That is ionic cli version. go to your ionic-bundle.js and there you can see the version. it will be something 1.0.0rc or beta ?

Comment: in rc1 they fixed that issue. I dont understand why its happening to you. Are you using <ion-scroll> anywhere ? 
PS. you can remove <ion-content scroll="true"> because it defaults to true only.

Comment: Upgrading to rc5 fixed the Problem >.< Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade the ionic javascript to the latest release candidate (currently rc5).